# Amazon API gateway -- proxied requests are returning unreadable data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We have recently begun exploring Amazon's api gateway service, and I have configured a few apis with explicit mapping.  These function as expected.

However, the proxy mapping seems to be returning unexpected/unreadable content.

This is what we get:

> ��������[o�0��J�Ů��-pǡ�j�Bڪ^�ɷīcg�CU��K

Also, this only occurs when we hit it from the application/Postman.  Doing test api calls from the gateway dashboard functions as expected.

Does it sound like some configuration is missing?  Anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your proxy mapping

Comment: The proxy mapping is a simple proxy in one particular resource bucket, for example:
'/foo/{proxy+}' 
Which functions as an http proxy that connects to our API being hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Could you provide an example of data returned by your elastic beanstalk application? What is the Content-Type specified in the response from your application?

Comment: The Content-Type is application/json.  Any of the data returned from our application would be in a standard json format. The api I was hitting is a simple GET api and ideally should return an array of json objects like:
[{category : "blah", displayText : "stuff"}, ...] but this is happening with any api I hit through this proxy endpoint.

Comment: You'd think "test" would mean "...in a meaningful way" but it is - or at least was - an unfortunate (and distinctly confusing) fact that testing in the API Gateway console is sometimes much further than you would imagine from being a valid simulation. Unless things have changed since I last tinkered with it, the test and "real" environment have odd and confusing behavioral discrepancies, so something this is not as unlikely as you might expect, though I have no idea why.  What about `Content-Encoding` (res) and `Accept-Encoding` (req) headers? Does your back-end perhaps blindly gzip responses?

Comment: Unfortunately @Michael-sqlbot is correct, there are still differences between testing from the console and executing a deployed API. We are working to address these as we identify them. Additionally, he is also correct that you should look at any Content-Encoding or Transfer-Encoding that your backend is producing as these can sometimes cause issues with proxied responses.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Michael-sqlbot for the advice.  It does appear that the request is being gzipped by the backend.  According to the AWS docs, gzip for proxy requests is not supported at this time so seems like that's it.  Thanks to everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment from Michael - sqlbot, the issue was with our backend compressing all responses with gzip.  AWS Api Gateway does not currently support gzip for proxy http requests. per https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=747449

> We don't currently support gzip. However you can workaround by using a lambda proxy for your POST method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html)