# Can/will AWS API Gateway -> Lambda performance be improved?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Has anyone found a solution to API Gateway latency issues?

With a simple function testing API Gateway -> Lambda interaction, I regularly see cold starts in the 2.5s range, and once "warmed," response times in the 900ms - 1.1s range are typical.

I understand the TLS handshake has its own overhead, but testing similar resources (AWS-based or general sites that I believe are not geo-distributed) from my location shows results that are half that, ~500ms.

Is good news coming soon from AWS?

(I've read everything I could find before posting.)

Comment: How long does it take to execute your function directly in AWS Lambda (using the **Test** button in console without API Gateway)?

Comment: @KhalidT. From the console? It's minuscule, of course: 16 or 18ms. These are "Hello world" equivalents used for testing response time. :)

Comment: Using the "Hello World" test might not reflect the actual execution time (unless you're using the same template when testing the API Gateway). Try to modify the template with real values that you usually expect to receive and will cause your function to run fully across all execution paths. The idea here is to figure out the bottleneck; whether it is the Lambda function itself or the API Gateway integration.

Comment: Nah, this is baseline performance. Posting with a payload is much the same, always ~1s total response time at best. Based on a number of posts, others note similar performance of API Gateway (not Lambda). What sort of times do you see?

Comment: Using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I usually have 250 ~ 350 ms response time on average for my Lambda functions (Node.js) using API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose everything's relative--how does it look in comparison to something like EC2, or similar options? I mentioned my own (subjective) comparison above, so there's a half-second or doubled difference in time. So basically, I can see it's slower...

Comment: And I can definitely see the difference in requests after the initial one, it's just that it's still slow for me, when assessing the viability of Lambda + API Gateway for my own use.

Comment: EC2 was not an option for me in my case. But if you can achieve a better performance with EC2, I don't see why not.

Comment: Which type are you using?  Python, Java, node, or c#?  I've always wondered if there was a performance difference between them...

Comment: Possibly useful in a roundabout way: as observed by me and subsequently confirmed by an API Gateway insider in the [comments on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40661591/1695906), the console test functionality of API Gateway has not historically been a perfect simulation of live behavior.  I would speculate that this may also explain some part of the performance discrepancy between test and live, although I have no idea what underlying factors cause the behavioral differences.

Comment: Where is your traffic originating from? This could be a CloudFront routing issue. What client are you using? If you can repeat this with a mock integration and no authentication, it is most likely networking related

Comment: I thought I had mentioned in my question, but apparently forgot--I'm `time`ing requests using `curl`. This is end-to-end. Other options (including EC2) halve the results, and others seem to note similarly slow results in blog posts and AWS forum questions.

Comment: There's so many unknowns here. You haven't said what your code does, what language it's written it, how you've packaged it or what memory allocation you've given it. You may not be keeping it warm enough either depending on your testing framework - that's if you have one, which is a must to ensure that you're get enough representative load. Consider committing more memory as this will ensure that your code runs on a higher spec. backend EC2 instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

engineer with the API Gateway team here.

You said you've read "everything", but for context for others I want to link to a number of threads on our forums where I've documented publicly where a lot of this perceived latency when executing a single API call comes from:

- [Forum Post 1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226136)
- [Forum Post 2](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225458)

In general, as you increase your call rates, your average latency will shrink as connection reuse mechanisms between your clients and CloudFront as well as between CloudFront and API Gateway can be leveraged. Additionally, a higher call rate will ensure your Lambda is "warm" and ready to serve requests.

That being said, we are painfully aware that we are not meeting the performance bar for a lot of our customers and are making strides towards improving this:

- The Lambda team is constantly working on improving cold start times as well as attempting to remove them for functions that are seeing continuous load.
- On API Gateway, we are currently in the process of rolling out improved connection reuse between CloudFront and API Gateway, where customers will be able to benefit from connections established via other APIs. This should mean that the percentage of requests that need to do a full TLS handshake between CloudFront and API Gateway should be reduced.